# CORS error only for a specific ROUTE in the API

Tags: php, laravel, apache, cors

I have the following problem:

I am using Laravel as API backend for some applications. For this I installed `"fruitcake/laravel-cors":"^2.0",` and set it up as follows:

config/cors.php

```php
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', 'logout', '/','*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Additionally I have the following .htaccess

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*".
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH".
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*".


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

My problem now is that everything works fine until I want to call the following route:

```
https://api.example.com/api/user
```

And only when I want to access the USER controller I get these errors:

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request does not pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

This is what the routes look like in `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    // lot more routes here

    Route::patch('/user/setting', [UserController::class, 'updateUserSetting']);
    Route::post('/user/setting', [UserController::class, 'setUserSetting']);
});
```

But really only with these two routes, all others go. I just don't understand it.

Comment: have you tried removing those header lines from the .htaccess ? Do you have other PATCH routes in that group ?

Comment: Yes and Yes, both the same

Comment: Can you get the response from the OPTIONS call in your browser Network History? I'm looking through `Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::handl()`, and one of the things it does is tap `Asm89\Stack\CorsService::handlePreflightRequest()` to do most of the heavy lifting. The first thing `handlePreflightRequest()` does is set the response code to 204, it's not even variable. (Of course that's "No content", not "Ok", but should work anyway.) I suspect there's something wring with your route definition. Could verify with `php artisan route:list`.